# pubcenter ads in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, ads

I have added this code for showing the ads on windows phone 8,
Tests Ads is coming correctly but when I replaced the ads settings with real AppId and UnitID then ads are not showing on phone. I am running the app in debug mode on device.

code :-

```
<!--<ui:AdControl 
            ApplicationId="actual id" 
            AdUnitId="unit id" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Height="80" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Width="480"
            IsBackgroundTransparent="True"
            />-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Add erroroccured event in your ad control and put a break point. I think you don't have ad for this category at this moment. If you want promote your app, add Aduplex for an additional ad. When pubcenter got no advertissement, display Aduplex.

Like this => http://blog.adduplex.com/2011/03/using-adduplex-as-fallback-for.html